# meta name viewport with No Zoom by default

Tags: html, css, mobile, meta-tags, meta

I want my website to fit to mobile devices screens. *No Horizontal Scrolling* by default, only vertical scrolling. I am using meta viewport as :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes ">
```

This is not working in mobile web browser, the website is zoomed with showing Horizontal scroll bar. User have to Zoom out and see the content. 
Test template of site is [waterbill.phed.co.in - meta viewport not working in mobile](http://waterbill.phed.co.in)

how to make site to fit to device width with No Zoom ?

Comment: From quick glance, you see to be using fixed width of 930px on #templatemo_footer, #services, #templatemo_welcome etc. Rewrite them using percentage and media queries.

Comment: changing them will completely change the design, is there any  other way to do so. by setting manual width ?

Comment: how to build site JUST using width % only, sometimes we required to specify the width in pixel to make accurate design. How to achieve that ?

Comment: You could use min-width and max-width in combination with percentage width. Regarding your previous question, you could use media queries to target specific devices. For example: on iphone, width can be 400px;

Comment: since it is to be developed in mvc4, and in mvc4 css are bundled. how to do that in mvc4. what should i do ?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" /> 
   Since example.css will be bundled in mvc4.

Comment: I see you are using templatemo's free templates. Why not use responsive bootstrap templates? They are mobile friendly. See http://startbootstrap.com/

Comment: could you suggest me link from where, i can learn How make site using width % and mobile friendly ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your website displays a horizontal scroll bar because some element(s) have widths that, possibly together with other elements widths, sum up to more than 100% of your available viewport's width.
You need to use percent as the unit when styling horizontal lengths. Note that this includes not only the elements' content boxes, but also elements' horizontal *paddings, borders and margins*. Of course, their sums should not exceed 100%. Also, using `box-sizing` may be of help to you.